# Should I use div or span for this example?

Tags: css, tags, html

So I want to code the content section that displays the title, author and the post itself, the code I'm using is where I want the title on top on one row, then the author on another row and content on another:

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="title">Title</div>
        <div class="author">Author</div>
        <div class="content">
            Content here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

or would span be a better choice like this?

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="container">
        <span class="title">Title</span>
        <span class="author">Author</span>
        <span class="content">
            Content here
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or is there a completely different and better way of doing this?

Thank you.

Comment: May be a better fit for [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I think span does not jump to new line. div is better i guess

Comment: Asuming you like them on seperate lines `<div>` is the way to go.

Comment: @Anne: Not at all. Being text-level semantics you'd want to use `span` over `div`. Multiple lines can be given by `display:block`. In this case however `p` would be more appropriate; `cite` and `q` or `blockquote` even more appropriate, depending on the `.content` content.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly that's a rather arbitrary thing, though.

Comment: @DA: it's in the specification. `div` is [grouping content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-div-element). The example given is to use a `div` to wrap *multiple* elements. `span` on the other hand is listed as [text-level semantics](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-span-element). `div` would be appropriate around multiple different text sections. `span` would be appropriate around individual text sections.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly I understand, but even as a specification, it's still rather arbitrary. DIV and SPANs are just generic containers. Yes, it makes sense to consider what you are saying, but it has absolutely no real bearing on the semantics or functionality of the markup.

Answer (score 1):

`div` is [grouping content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html) and `span` is [text-level semantics](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html). Of the two examples given, the latter is what you'd be better using:

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="container">
        <span class="title">Title</span>
        <span class="author">Author</span>
        <span class="content">
            Content here
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Depending on what is contained within `.content` you may want to use `div` for that, however.

To properly conform with the specification you should use [`cite`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-cite-element) for the title. Equally, if your `.content` is a quote or extract you should use [`q`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-q-element) or [`blockquote`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-blockquote-element)

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="container">
        <cite class="title">Title</cite>
        <span class="author">Author</span>
        <q class="content">
            Content here
        </q>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try HTML semantic markup instead of `div`s?

```
<section id="main">
    <article>
        <hgroup>
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <h2>author</h2>
        </hgroup>
        <section>
            Content
        </section>
    </article>
</section>
```

Comment: This is great, but how would you rate it against Tom Walters answer? Cause I really like his answer as well. Not sure which one would be better to use.

Comment: You should take HTML5 only when you're ready to change all site markup, not only that one part. Otherwise, it would be confusing.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter. All of the answers espousing one over the other are fine, but pretty much arbitrary opinions.

In the end, both `DIV` and `SPAN` are just generic containers. They don't mean anything in and of themselves.

So, if you have to choose between one of those two, it doesn't matter. However, due to your one requirement:

> is where I want the title on top on one row, then the author on another row and content on another

...I'd suggest going with a `DIV` for no other reason than a div, by default, is a block level element, meaning it will automatically be formatted into individual lines for you.

All that said, everyone that is suggestion that you perhaps consider a more semantic container is spot-on. Would this be better treated as a `ol`? Or perhaps even just `p` tags?

Answer (score 0):

If the question is only a choice between `div` and `span` then the answer is...

`span` is used for the individual elements, and `div` for blocks.

The second variant is better than the first.

See [Grouping elements: the DIV and SPAN elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.4) for more info.

Here is quote from there:

> These elements define content to be inline (SPAN) or block-level (DIV)

Answer (score 0):

The `<div>` tag should be used for *dividing* up your page into logical blocks. Here a `<span>` would be more appropriate.

**However** as you're displaying text what's wrong with something like:

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="container">
        <h2 class="title">Title</h2>
        <a class="author">Author</a>
        <p class="content">
            Content here
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

After all, they're designed specifically for text.

Comment: This works great, thanks. Though another user (Marcin) suggested using semantic markups instead. Would you say this or the one he suggested is better? Thanks.

Comment: It depends on the content, if it's a standalone article then the other answer is great! Otherwise this one works just as well.